# mgwt attach CellSelectedHandler to GroupingCellList inside HeaderList

Tags: gwt, mgwt, celllist

I'm having trouble attaching an SelectionHandler to the contents of the mgwt HeaderList.
How can I attach a CellSelectedHandler to a HeaderList just like in the Showcase?
http://mobilegwt.appspot.com/showcase/#GroupedCellListPlace:

I already tryed to attach the Handler to the GrouingCellList with wich the HeaderList is built, but this Handler is never fired.

Anyone done this already?

Comment: I've done with CellList and its handlers..is it useful to you?

Comment: With the CellList I was also successfull, but with the GroupingCellList inside the HeaderList it seems not to work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the SelectEvents using the SelectionHandler instead of the CellSelectedHandler on the GroupingCellList

```
        addHandlerRegistration(view.getList().addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Content>(){
        @Override
         public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Content> event) {
                Window.alert("event"+event.getSelectedItem().getName());
        }
    }));
```